# How to improve the sharpness of the output video on centOS?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the same ffmpeg cmd on Windows and centOS to add timecode for the input video, the output video on centOS has low sharpness and mosaic.

**ffmpeg version:**

```
ffmpeg on Windows: 4.1.3 built with gcc 8.3.1 (gcc) 20190414

ffmpeg on centOS: 4.1.0 built with gcc 5.8.5(gcc) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
```

**ffmpeg cmd:**

```
ffmpeg -i \input.mp4 -vf drawtext="timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=30:x=10:y=10:text=qwer:fontsize=50:fontcolor=yellow:boxcolor=black" \output.mp4
```

**Video screenshot:**

[output video on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfT2d.jpg)

[output video on centOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJx90.jpg)

**full log on centOS:**

```
[root@3b8e5c174983 installfile]# ls
ffmpeg-4.1.3  ffmpeg-4.1.3.tar.gz  input.mp4  yasm-1.3.0  yasm-1.3.0.tar.gz
[root@3b8e5c174983 installfile]# ffmpeg -i /installfile/input.mp4  -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/lyx/simhei.ttf:timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=30:x=10:y=10:text=qwer:fontsize=50:fontcolor=black" /installfile/output.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)
  configuration: --enable-libfreetype
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/installfile/input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
  Duration: 00:00:25.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3620 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 1920x1080, 3490 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to '/installfile/output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame=  769 fps=108 q=31.0 Lsize=   10290kB time=00:00:25.70 bitrate=3279.4kbits/s speed=3.62x    
video:9870kB audio:397kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.222400%
[aac @ 0x37dbec0] Qavg: 2346.057
[root@3b8e5c174983 installfile]#
```

it's about the version of ffmpeg?

Comment: Share the full log for the CentOS command.

Comment: Set a bitrate or a crf value.

Comment: Above is the full log for the CentOS command. I compare with Windows. The difference is: on centOS, the output video's encoder turns into mpeg4(input video's encoder is h264. If use ffmpeg to cheange the video's encoder from h264 turns into mpeg4, even on Windwos, the output video also will have low sharpness as the same) . I guess that is the reason. Now, how to fix it?

Comment: ffmpeg -codecs:   D.V.LS h264 .  h246 encode is disable, so ffmpeg use mpeg4 encode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` on CentOS is not configured to use the encoder *libx264* (H.264), so it is using the encoder *mpeg4* (MPEG-4 Part 2) instead. This encoder is an older generation and is less efficient.

If you want to continue using mpeg4 then add `-q:v 2` to increase output quality.

If you want to output H.264 then you need to re-compile `ffmpeg` with `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264` (and `--enable-libfreetype` for the drawtext filter). See [FFmpeg Wiki: CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) for a compile guide, or [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) an already compiled binary that has support for libx264.

You can add `-c:a copy` if you don't need to re-encode the audio since the input and output are both AAC.

Comment: Accurate! Actually, I re-compiled ffmpeg on CentOS to enable libx264 yesterday. And all I need is drawtext func and encoder h264. The static build is more suitable. Thanks.